# React-Router Nested Routes not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

### Steps to reproduce

**client.js (entry file)**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducers from './reducers';
import routes from './routes.js';

const storeWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
const store = storeWithMiddleware(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**routes.js (ver 1)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/bases/app.js';
import Login from './components/app/authentication/login.js';

export default(
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="signup" component={Login}/>
  </Route>
)
```

**routes.js (ver 2)**

```
let routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    { path: 'signup', component: Login }
  ]
}

export default routes;
```

### Expected Behavior

Expect to have `/signup` route avail.

### Actual Behavior

react-router cannot find the route `/signup` but can find `/`

Having a look at the chrome dev-tools source-tab, this is what I find:

**When looking at "/"**

```
sources
--------
dist/prod
|     bundle.js
index.html
```

**When looking at "/signup"**

```
sources
--------
signup
```

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: I tried using `webpack-dev-server` and `http-server`

Comment: Can you verify if this works/fails when you use `hashHistory`. I think that it should and that it is a server issue.

Comment: I have imported hashHistory but what's the equivalent `example.com/signup` route using `hashHistory`?

Comment: Should be `example.com/#/signup` (I believe the default `hashHistory` includes a starting slash)

Comment: oh wow it does work with `hashHistory`! do you know what causes this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you changed to hashHistory and it worked it probably be your backend which serves the html...

Since hashHistory works like this:

```
example.com/#/signup
```

The browser doesn't understand as a new GET, if you use browseHistory, this:

```
example.com/signup
```

Makes the browser request for index.html again but on path /signup ... but the webpack dev server probably don't understand..
Try adding historyApiFallback: true to webpack config
LIke this

https://github.com/amacneil/react-router-webpack-history-example

Comment: unfortunately I still get the same issue. It works on the `"/"` route but not `"/signup"`

Comment: The component App has a `{this.props.children}` ?

Comment: yep.

`import React, { Component } from 'react';
import connect from 'react-redux';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        hi
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}`

Comment: hmmm.. If you change the browseHistory to hashHistory does it work?

Comment: I have imported hashHistory but what's the equivalent `example.com/signup` route using `hashHistory`?

Comment: oh wow it does work with `hashHistory`! do you know what causes this issue?

Comment: What if my backend is completely separate from the front-end react app and the intention is to host the static react app on something like aws s3?

Comment: Then you need to use hashHIstory... I anwser something like that in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776651/can-i-create-routes-with-react-router-for-a-github-pages-site/40797235#40797235 ... but instead of s3... it was github pages

Comment: I see! would there be a way to physically change the url so it's more "user friendly"?

Comment: I don t think so... I think it already is user friendly. hash routing was already used by angular and it just has a # char...

Answer (score 1):

The giveaway is the files that are being served when you are looking at the sources. When you are trying to load the `/signup` page, your browser is trying to load a `signup` page.

When you use `browserHistory`, you need to serve your `index.html` (and any scripts included in it) for all possible routes. This means that you need to have a server which accepts all possible routes and responds accordingly.

For example, if you are running a node server using `express`, you would need to have a wildcard route handler:

```
// define static handler first for .js, etc.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// all other routes should server your index.html file
app.get("/", handleRender);
app.get("*", handleRender);

function handleRender(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
}
```

Comment: What if my backend is completely separate from the front-end react app and the intention is to host the static react app on something like aws s3?

Comment: For static pages, you have to use a hash history. I wrote an expanded explanation in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687493/seeing-empty-page-after-deployed-to-s3-with-react-route/40689458#40689458

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for that detailed explanation Paul :)