# IndexRoute not showing when pushing to GH Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router, github-pages

I am having a slight issue with my React Router setup, but after sifting around for a while on Stack Overflow and GH, I have not been able to tweak my code to working order.

My issue is that when uploading to GH Pages the index route renders my default NoMatch component, instead of my Home component. When running the same application on a local server the localhost:3000 renders Home correctly.

My routes are set up like so:

```js
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path="home" component={Home} />
      <Route path="projects" component={Projects} /> 
      <Route path="photography" component={Photography} />
      <Route path="about" component={About} /> 
      <Route path="contact" component={Contact} />
      <Route path="creativeprocess" component={CreativeProcess} />
      <Route path="readinglist" component={ReadingList} />
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
    </Route>
  </Router>),
  document.getElementById('root')
```

And my App.js has a header section and then follows it up with a div for {this.props.children}. On GH Pages and local all routes work as intended except the IndexRoute on initial render.

How do I make the Home component the default component when pushing to GH Pages?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Have you got a fiddle? That would help us.

Comment: I think you can remove `<Route path="home" component={Home} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub Pages serves static content, but you are using the `browserHistory` which requires some sort of router on the server to serve pages. For static content, you should be using `hashHistory`.

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path="home" component={Home} />
      <Route path="projects" component={Projects} /> 
      <Route path="photography" component={Photography} />
      <Route path="about" component={About} /> 
      <Route path="contact" component={Contact} />
      <Route path="creativeprocess" component={CreativeProcess} />
      <Route path="readinglist" component={ReadingList} />
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

I wrote a long-ish explanation on why you want to use `hashHistory` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687493/seeing-empty-page-after-deployed-to-s3-with-react-route/40689458#40689458), but the gist of it is that when a user navigates to a page that your application is hosted at, they should always be served your application. The application will use the current URL to determine what to render.

For a static site, there is no back end to serve the correct files no matter the path. In order to guarantee that all routes serve the correct content, you should use a hash history. When using a hash history, the path before the hash is where your html file is located, and the hash will be used to determine which route to render.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation Paul! I actually realized why hashHistory should be used yesterday, when I ran into the issue you mentioned on another website. It made sense then that if someone was to try to link to some content on my static site, they would not be able to access the content properly.

Answer (score 0):

Arun, since this was pertaining to rendering the app on the GitHub server, I don't believe a fiddle would have provided much in terms of showing the issue. I did figure it out though, I changed Route path="/" to Route path="/stasreactapp", which is the name of my repository on GitHub, and the identifier for the GH page URL. That means the local server will need to run on "3000/stasreactapp". Then I changed all of the subroutes to something like "/home" instead of just "home".

These changes have solved the rendering on the GH Page, and all seems to be working well now!

The page itself is at https://mym1990.github.io/reactstasapp/